# Why is it that when I make the user add a row to the csv file, it also adds an empty row, making it print only records with an even number?

Tags: python, csv

This is what I have put in the `csv` file:

```
import csv

with open('stuff.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    mywriter.writerow(['Artist', 'Track', 'Album', 'Year', 'Genre'])
    mywriter.writerow(['Rolling Stones', 'Satisfaction', 'Sticky Fingers', '1980', 'Rock'])
    mywriter.writerow(['ATTLAS', 'Taylor', 'Siren EP', '2015', 'Electronic'])
    mywriter.writerow(['ATTLAS', 'Luna', 'Siren EP', '2015', 'Electronic'])
    mywriter.writerow(['ATTLAS', 'Parallel Lines', 'Sin EP', '2015', 'Electronic'])
    mywriter.writerow(['Bonobo', 'Cirrus', 'The North Borders', '2013', 'Electronic'])
```

This is my code for making the user add a row to the csv file:

```
if userAction == "2":
            List = []
            artist = str(input("What is the artist? "))
            track = str(input("What is the name of the track? "))
            album = str(input("What is the name of the album? "))
            year = str(input("What year was it released? "))
            genre = str(input("What genre would the track fit into? "))
            List.append(artist)
            List.append(track)
            List.append(album)
            List.append(year)
            List.append(genre)
            with open(r'stuff.csv', 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(List)

            print("Here is the new database; ")
            viewDatabase()
```

This is `viewDatabase()`:

```
def viewDatabase():
    myList = []
    with open('stuff.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for i, row in enumerate(myreader):
            myList = row
            if myList != []:
               if i == 0:
                   pass
               else:
                   print("\nRECORD", i)
                   print("Artist: ", myList[0])
                   print("Track: ", myList[1])
                   print("Album: ", myList[2])
                   print("Year: ", myList[3])
                   print("Genre: ", myList[4])
```

When I type 2 to make the user add a row to the csv file and the `viewDatabase` function runs, this happens:

```
RECORD 5
Artist:  Bonobo
Track:  Cirrus
Album:  The North Borders
Year:  2013
Genre:  Electronic

RECORD 6
Artist:  bob
Track:  bob
Album:  bob
Year:  bob
Genre:  bob

RECORD 8
Artist:  dan
Track:  dan
Album:  dan
Year:  dan
Genre:  dan

RECORD 10
Artist:  sam
Track:  sam
Album:  sam
Year:  sam
Genre:  sam
If you wish to continue, press enter. If not, press any key.
```

After the fifth record, which *I* entered, the record numbers are always even when they should be consecutive.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What does the contents of stuff.csv look like?  Are there any blank lines in it?

Comment: `viewDatabase` is missing something.  Are you using a `csv.reader` to read the file?

Answer (score 1):

Well when you initially open the file, you explicitely ask not to add an additional `\n` after each row with `newline=''`, which is correct. But when you later open it to add a new record, you fail to do the same, so each row is followed by an additional end of line.

You just have to open the file that way:

```
...
with open(r'stuff.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    ...
```